# Creating an array of keyword search terms using Python

Tags: python, firebase, search, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

I am trying to use Python to create an array of letters that build into the full name of the word that will be ultimately used for keyword searches in a web application that I'm building.

Essentially, reads and writes in Cloud Firestore can get expensive and my understanding is that using an array of letters significantly reduces the number of reads necessary for people to use if you're using an asynchronous search function.

I'm wanting to iterate over my original text files, pull out two columns (uuid and company name) and then build a keyword search term for the company name. I need uuid so I can update the Firebase Firestore record once I've got the complete array.

So, the company "WetPaint"'s search term array becomes:

```
W
We
Wet 
WetP
WetPa
WetPai
WetPain
WetPaint
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
keywords = ""
arrName = []

with open ('org_test.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader=csv.DictReader(csv_file,delimiter=',')
    line_count=0
    for row in csv_reader:
                uuid=row['uuid']
                name=row['name']
                lowerc = name.lower()
                for c in lowerc:
                    keywords += c
                    arrName = keywords
                    print(uuid, arrName)
csv_file.close()
```

From my example file, that actually gives me (and yes, I want it lower case):

```
e1393508-30ea-8a36-3f96-dd3226033abd w
e1393508-30ea-8a36-3f96-dd3226033abd we
e1393508-30ea-8a36-3f96-dd3226033abd wet
e1393508-30ea-8a36-3f96-dd3226033abd wetp
e1393508-30ea-8a36-3f96-dd3226033abd wetpa
e1393508-30ea-8a36-3f96-dd3226033abd wetpai
e1393508-30ea-8a36-3f96-dd3226033abd wetpain
e1393508-30ea-8a36-3f96-dd3226033abd wetpaint
bf4d7b0e-b34d-2fd8-d292-6049c4f7efc7 wetpaintz
bf4d7b0e-b34d-2fd8-d292-6049c4f7efc7 wetpaintzo
bf4d7b0e-b34d-2fd8-d292-6049c4f7efc7 wetpaintzoh
bf4d7b0e-b34d-2fd8-d292-6049c4f7efc7 wetpaintzoho
5f2b40b8-d1b3-d323-d81a-b7a8e89553d0 wetpaintzohod
5f2b40b8-d1b3-d323-d81a-b7a8e89553d0 wetpaintzohodi
5f2b40b8-d1b3-d323-d81a-b7a8e89553d0 wetpaintzohodig
5f2b40b8-d1b3-d323-d81a-b7a8e89553d0 wetpaintzohodigg
```

I know the issue is that my first for loop isn't "starting over" or zeroing out when it gets to the next company name in the list but I don't know how to fix it. It's also not really an array either.

This is the way it "should" look:

```
e1393508-30ea-8a36-3f96-dd3226033abd w
e1393508-30ea-8a36-3f96-dd3226033abd we
e1393508-30ea-8a36-3f96-dd3226033abd wet
e1393508-30ea-8a36-3f96-dd3226033abd wetp
e1393508-30ea-8a36-3f96-dd3226033abd wetpa
e1393508-30ea-8a36-3f96-dd3226033abd wetpai
e1393508-30ea-8a36-3f96-dd3226033abd wetpain
e1393508-30ea-8a36-3f96-dd3226033abd wetpaint
bf4d7b0e-b34d-2fd8-d292-6049c4f7efc7 z
bf4d7b0e-b34d-2fd8-d292-6049c4f7efc7 zo
bf4d7b0e-b34d-2fd8-d292-6049c4f7efc7 zoh
bf4d7b0e-b34d-2fd8-d292-6049c4f7efc7 zoho
5f2b40b8-d1b3-d323-d81a-b7a8e89553d0 d
5f2b40b8-d1b3-d323-d81a-b7a8e89553d0 di
5f2b40b8-d1b3-d323-d81a-b7a8e89553d0 dig
5f2b40b8-d1b3-d323-d81a-b7a8e89553d0 digg
```

And I need to be able to store these values as one array in Firestore:

For the company named, "digg". Keywords: ["d", "di", "dig", "digg"]

Answer (score 1):

Just declare `keywords` inside the outer `for` loop:

```py
with open ('org_test.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        uuid = row['uuid']
        name = row['name'].lower()
        keywords = ''
        for c in name:
            keywords += c
            print(uuid, keywords)
```

Also note that there's no need for `csv_file.close()` since you're using the `with` keyword.

Comment: Thank you so much. Looks like I was very close and you're correct. I forgot that I only need to use close() when I use open() but not with. I can't believe I didn't see the variable declaration as the solution. One last question- "keywords" is a variable but it's not an array. How do I add the values that I've been accumulating with the for loop but convert it into an array?

Answer (score 1):

Declaring both the variables inside the loop should solve it.

```
with open ('org_test.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        uuid = row['uuid']
        name = row['name'].lower()
        keywords = ''
        arrName = []
        for c in name:
            keywords += c
            arrName.append(keywords)
        print(uuid, arrName)
```

Comment: Excellent! This works perfectly. Now I'm trying to update the records in Firebase and I get this error: e1393508-30ea-8a36-3f96-dd3226033abd ['w', 'we', 'wet', 'wetp', 'wetpa', 'wetpai', 'wetpain', 'wetpaint']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keywords.py", line 107, in <module>
    doc_ref = store.collection("org_test").where("uuid", "==", uuid).update(data)
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'update'. I've tried update and set but I get the same error. Data is simply: data = {u'keywords': arrName}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!

This was the final version that worked:

```
with open (file) as csv_file:
    csv_reader=csv.DictReader(csv_file,delimiter=',')
    line_count=0
    co = []

    for row in csv_reader:

                # Initialize variables
                uuid=row["uuid"]
                name=row["name"].lower()
                primary_role=row["primary_role"]
                cb_url=row["cb_url"]
                domain=row["domain"]
                homepage_url=row["homepage_url"]
                logo_url=row["logo_url"]
                facebook_url=row["facebook_url"]
                twitter_url=row["twitter_url"]
                linkedin_url=row["linkedin_url"]
                combined_stock_symbols=row["combined_stock_symbols"]
                city=row["city"]
                region=row["region"]
                country_code=row["country_code"]
                short_description=row["short_description"]
                keywords = ""
                arrName = []
                clean = []

                # Loop to create searchable keywords
                for c in name:
                    keywords += c
                    arrName.append(keywords)

                doc_ref = db.collection("orgs").document()
                doc_ref.set({
                    u'uuid': uuid,
                    u'name': name,
                    u'keywords': ArrayUnion(arrName),
                    u'primary_role':primary_role,
                    u'cb_url': cb_url,
                    u'domain': domain,
                    u'homepage_url': homepage_url,
                    u'logo_url': logo_url,
                    u'facebook_url': facebook_url,
                    u'twitter_url': twitter_url,
                    u'linkedin_url': linkedin_url,
                    u'combined_stock_symbols': combined_stock_symbols,
                    u'city': city,
                    u'region': region,
                    u'country_code': country_code,
                    u'short_description': short_description
                    })
```